# AS3: Accesing movieclip in button

Tags: actionscript-3, simplebutton

I was trying to access movieclip located in a button, which i refer by this code:

```
var buttonObject = this[weaponsPurchased[i]];
```

Then i'm setting "mouseEnabled" false (that part works)

```
buttonObject.mouseEnabled = false;
```

And then i'm trying to set a movieclip inside this button unvisible (and that doesn't work)

```
buttonObject["square"].visible = false;
```

I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property square not found on
>   flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value.     at (...)

I didn't find any help on the internet, so please help me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make the MovieClip in the button with the IDE or did you use `addChild()`?

Comment: I think the best course of action is to use `addChild()` to avoid complications.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access child elements of a SimpleButton. SimpleButtons are not DisplayObjectContainers, yet they can have child elements when being created from the Flash IDE.

Source: http://xtyler.com/as3-simple-button-breaking-all-rules/

I would just go with a MovieClip instead with your own class to handle MouseOver and MouseOut events. A good tutorial outlines the creation of a reusable button class that extends MovieClip.

http://www.ironcoding.com/2011/02/flash-as3-movieclip-button-tutorial/

Comment: Now i'm getting ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property getChildByName not found on flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value.

Comment: I was wrong, a SimpleButton is a DisplayObject; not a DisplayObjectContainer. Is your simpleButton created in the flash IDE?

Comment: I changed the answer, try it out.

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Flash is such a troll...

Comment: Did you save the class as MySimpleButton.as and assign the class to the SimpleButton?

Comment: Yes. I don't get this error, when i remove buttonObject["square"].visible = false; line. Even tried with adding a method, but still not working.

Comment: Seems like it's impossible to access movieclip inside a button.

Comment: I just went through and tested it myself and you definitely can not access child elements of a SimpleButton via code. I will adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago. What I did was to search for the DisplayObject inside of each state of the button. I'll drop some code here that might help you. You must realize that if your button have objects in all four frames, you will find your object in all the states as well.

```
    private var Obj1:DisplayObject, Obj2:DisplayObject, 
    Obj3:DisplayObject, Obj2:DisplayObject;

    private function searchInChildren(spr:DisplayObject, name:String):void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < spr.numChildren; i++) 
        {
            if(spr.getChildAt(i).name == name)
            {
                return spr.getChildAt(i);
            }           
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function searchControllers(_ref:SimpleButton, name:String):void
    {   
        try{
            Obj1 = searchInChildren(_ref.upState, name);
            Obj2 = searchInChildren(_ref.overState, name);
            Obj3 = searchInChildren(_ref.downState, name);
            Obj4 = searchInChildren(_ref.hitTestState, name);
        } catch (e:Error) {
            trace("error: "+e+", when trying to search for controllers");
        }
    }
```